# How to get AWSCredentials given a AWS Cognito access_token

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In an android app, I receive a JWT access_token from `http://<domain>.auth.<region>.amazoncognito.com/login` once the user is done authenticating to a Cognito User Pool. That User Pool is linked to a Cognito Identity Pool.

What API should I call with that access_token to get an `AWSCredentials` object.

The closest one I found would be [AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity.html), but that is an STS API, and some of what I've read on the web seems to recommend developers not use STS directly but rely on Cognito.

Moreover, I do not expect the API I need to require specifying a role name. Cognito Identity Pools are already configured to give authenticated users a specific role. And AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity takes a role name as input to the API. Hence that does not look like right.

I've looked at [Cognito Identity Pool API Reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html), and can't find an API that takes access_token and return AWS credentials.

**UPDATE:**
The following answer which uses `GetCredentialsForIdentity` throws `ResourceNotFoundException` saying it cannot find the specified IdentityId.

```
string access_token = ...
var jwtAccessToken = System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.JwtSecurityToken(access_token);

var client = new AmazonCognitoIdentityClient(new AnonymousAWSCredentials(),REGION);

var response = await client.GetCredentialsForIdentityAsync(new GetCredentialsForIdentityRequest
{
    IdentityId=String.Format("{0}:{1}", REGION, jwtAccessToken.id),
    Logins=new Dictionary<string,string> 
    { 
        {String.Format("cognito-idp.{0}.amazonaws.com/{1}", REGION, USER_POOL_ID),
         access_token}
    }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After much investigation, I found the answer.

1- One needs an `id_token` not an `access_token` to authenticate to Cognito, as misleading as this might sound. AWS's documentation which says you ask for id_token when you need to have user attributes like name / email etc... and ask for an access_token when you don't need that information and just want to authenticate is wrong, or at the very least misleading.

2- And here's how you use an id-token to get AWS Credentials:

```
var credentials = CognitoAWSCredentials(<identity pool Id>, region);
credentials.AddLogin(
    "cognito-idp.<region>.amazonaws.com/<user_pool_id>",
    id_token); // the raw token
```

Note that you do not need `AssumeRoleWithIdentity`, or `GetCredentialsWithIdentity`, you do not even need a `AmazonCognitoIdentityClient`.

Comment: thanks - this was the last piece of the immense puzzle that is Cognito

Answer (score 0):

To get the credentials you can use [GetCredentialsForIdentity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetCredentialsForIdentity.html) method by passing the JWT token. This method is implemented in [AmazonCognitoIdentityClient](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android/blob/master/aws-android-sdk-core/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/cognitoidentity/AmazonCognitoIdentityClient.java) class in the AWS Android SDK.

IAM Role should be defined in the Cognito Federated Identities. This limits the assuming role to be handled internally, by Cognito not allowing the mobile app to assume any other role than the one configured. In addition you shouldn't give this role IAM permission, allowing the Android SDK to assume different roles (Unless its a superuser kind of a user who is logging in).

Comment: I don't see how the `GetCredentialsForIdentity` API takes in an access_token? It needs an `IdentityId` which lools like the Cognito Identity Pool Id, and a `Logins` which is how one would input the username (along with the name of the social identity provider). I do not have that Login information. What I do have is a Cognito JWT access_token (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html)

Comment: Inside the Logins Map, you can provide the JWT token.

Comment: I've updated my question with code that implements your suggestion, it throws an exception. Are you sure you can provide access_tokens in lieu of a username? and If so what do you specify for the IdentityId?

Comment: Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
logins.put("cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_123456678", '<id-token>');

Comment: that's exactly what I have (though written in C# in my case, see my updated question). It barks at the IdentityId not at the Logins. What's IdentityId, all I have is the identity pool id, and the token.

Comment: Also you say "id-token" I actually have an access_token, I'm pretty sure those are different.

Comment: I also try to crack open the JWT access token, get the Id inside it, use that to fill in the `IdentityId` part of the request. Still get `ResourceNotFoundException` (see the Update paragraph in my question for the exact code).

Comment: If you use OpenID Scope, you will receive the ID token which can be used to authenticate

Comment: Ok, but the user is already authenticated here, AWS returned an access_token, that is more powerful than an id token. What do I do with it?