# What kind of token does 'Addlogin' method take?

Tags: amazon-cognito

[Addlogin](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/v3/apidocs/items/CognitoIdentity/MCognitoAWSCredentialsAddLoginStringString.html) takes two parameters, first one being pretty straight forward. Second one takes "token provided by the identity provider".

I've been trying to use IdToken provided by google sign-in on Unity, but it doesn't seem to do anything. So I thought I should get access token with authcode provided, but if I figure out what token Addlogin takes, that wouldn't be necessary...

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering or need clarification, I'll leave here what I found.

Addlogin takes `id_token` not `access_token` according to [accepted answer in this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49722333/how-to-get-awscredentials-given-a-aws-cognito-access-token)